# Why these grey elements appear in the vs codes when I use an arrow key?

Tags: vscode-extensions

[image: VS code screen pic]

I can't get rid of these grey elements in VS code. It appears everywhere before the arrow (=>) key in the code. Can anybody explain it to me?

Extension ID: styled-components.vscode-styled-components v1.7.5

Comment: [edit] your post to tell us the IDs of the extensions that you have installed and activated for this workspace

Answer (score 0):

These are so-called inlay hints, which you can enable in the settings (search for "inlay"). Check also [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUvTP0QvSms) for a quick introduction to this feature.

Comment: thanks a lot. It helped. Actually the inlay hints were enabled. I have disabled it now and all these grey text elements are gone

Comment: Great I could help. If you find my answer helpful then please accept it by ticking the gray checkmark left to the answer.